# Adding Transition to Color Change in React Native Slider Radio

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile

I'm working on a React Native project and using the `SliderPicker` component for selecting options. The component changes the background color when an option is selected, but I want to add a smooth transition effect to the text color change as well.

Here is the `SliderPicker` component I'm using:

```js
import React, {
    useEffect,
    useRef,
    useState
} from 'react';
import {
    Text,
    View,
    TouchableHighlight,
    LayoutAnimation
} from 'react-native';

function SliderPicker({
    options,
    onOptionPick
}) {
    const [pickedOption, pickOption] = useState([]);
    const optionsRef = useRef({});

    const handleOptionPick = (key) => {
        const optionPressed = optionsRef.current;

        optionPressed[key].measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
            LayoutAnimation.configureNext({
                duration: 200,
                update: {
                    type: LayoutAnimation.Types.easeInEaseOut,
                },
            });
            pickOption([key, width, pageX]);
        });
    };

    return ( <
        View className = "flex-row items-center justify-between mt-2 mx-5 p-1.5 rounded-xl bg-midnightBlue" >
        <
        View className = "h-full absolute rounded-lg bg-majorelleBlue"
        style = {
            {
                left: (pickedOption.length !== 0 && pickedOption[2] - 20),
                width: (pickedOption.length !== 0 && pickedOption[1])
            }
        }
        /> {
            options.map((option) => ( <
                View className = "flex-1"
                key = {
                    option.key
                }
                ref = {
                    (ref) => (optionsRef.current[option.key] = ref)
                } >
                <
                TouchableHighlight underlayColor = "transparent"
                onPress = {
                    () => {
                        handleOptionPick(option.key);
                        console.log(option.key)
                    }
                } >
                <
                Text className = {
                    `py-0.5 text-center font-montsemi text-xl bg-transparent`
                } > {
                    option.label
                } <
                /Text> <
                /TouchableHighlight> <
                /View>
            ))
        } <
        /View>
    );
}

export default SliderPicker;
```

I've already added a transition effect to the background color change, but I'm unsure how to achieve the same effect for the text color. Any guidance or code examples on how to implement this transition would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!
btw I use nativewind